# To display random questions

Tags: php, mysql

I am designing a test where in I want to display questions randomly. I have 50 questions in the database. For this I have written the following code :

```
$singleSQL = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM questions WHERE id='$question' ORDER BY Rand()"); 

        while($row = mysql_fetch_array($singleSQL)){
            $id = $row['id'];
            $thisQuestion = $row['question'];
            $type = $row['type'];
            $question_id = $row['question_id'];
            $q = '<h2>'.$thisQuestion.'</h2>';
            $sql2 = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM answers WHERE question_id='$question' ORDER BY rand()");
            while($row2 = mysql_fetch_array($sql2)){
                $answer = $row2['answer'];
                $correct = $row2['correct'];
                $answers .= '<label style="cursor:pointer;"><input type="radio" name="rads" value="'.$correct.'">'.$answer.'</label> 
                <input type="hidden" id="qid" value="'.$id.'" name="qid"><br /><br />
                ';

            }
            $output = ''.$q.','.$answers.',<span id="btnSpan"><button onclick="post_answer()">Submit</button></span>';
            echo $output;
           }
```

This rand() function in the first line is not working for questions but the same function is working for answers(options of MCQs appears randomly).
Also when I do changes in sql query in the first line I get the error :

Warning:

```
mysql_fetch_array() expects parameter 1 to be resource
boolean given in C:\xampp\htdocs\questions.php on line 36
undefined.
```

I dont know what's wrong!! Pls help me out..!!

Comment: `$singleSQL = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM questions ORDER BY Rand()");`

Isn't this enough for random selection of questions.?

Comment: Do not use `mysql_*` API. This is deprecated. Use ' mysqli_*`ord pdo with prepared statements. Where do you connect to the database? Which line is line 36?

Comment: Put `or die(mysql_error())` after `mysql_query()` so you see the SQL error message.

Comment: What is the name of the ID column in the `questions` table? Your first query uses `id`, but in the `while` loop you use `$row['question_id']`. Which is right?

Answer (score 0):

The `WHERE id = '$question'` clause in the first query is making it return just a single question that matches that ID, not all the questions. You need to remove that.

```
$singleSQL = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM questions ORDER BY Rand()");
```

And inside the loop, you're using the wrong variable in the second query. It should be:

```
$sql2 = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM answers WHERE question_id='$question_id' ORDER BY rand()");
```

Comment: I have made changes in "SELECT * FROM answers WHERE question_id='$question_id' ORDER BY rand()" this query. Also I have removed where clause. Now random questions are coming, but at a time 2 questions are appearing instead of one.

Comment: Why should it return only one question? It should return ALL the questions in a random order. If you only want one question, use LIMIT 1. Then you don't need the `while($row = mysql_fetch_array())` loop, since there's just one row.

Comment: I removed the while loop and also I used LIMIT 1, but the questions are not coming in  random order. I am trying to make a test where in people sitting on adjacent systems should not have the same question at the same time. That is why I wanted only one question at a time.

Comment: I didn't wonder why you wanted one question at a time, I wondered why you thought the code you posted would do it. I don't know why you're not getting a random question, `ORDER BY RAND()` works for everyone else.

Answer (score 0):

**Extra information on ORDER BY Rand():**

ORDER BY Rand() works fine when you are working with small database, say, 1000 rows. But when it comes to large database it cause performance problem. Read 
[this article](http://jan.kneschke.de/projects/mysql/order-by-rand/) for more information and alternate solution.

As of your question, Barmar point out exactly what's wrong with the code.

```
1. $singleSQL = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM questions WHERE id='$question' ORDER BY Rand()");
```

Here you are randomizing for only one row which make no sense.

```
2. mysql_query("SELECT * FROM answers WHERE question_id='$question' ORDER BY    rand()");
```

It should be WHERE id='$question_id' instead of WHERE id='$question'